# Reading/Writing Files in Java and Adding Line Numbers

Tags: java, io, numbers, try-catch, copy-paste

I have the following assignment to complete:

Wrote a program that reads a file and writes a copy of the file to another file with line numbers inserted.

So far, I wrote the code that is posted below. This code reads and copies the text to another file, but I cannot figure out how to number each line in the new text file. Can someone please advise me on how to do so?

```
import java.io.*;

class FileCopy
{
   public static void main(String[] args) 
   {
      try 
      {
         File fileIn  = new File("Assign4.txt");
         File fileOut = new File("target.txt");

         FileInputStream streamIn   = new FileInputStream(fileIn);
         FileOutputStream streamOut = new FileOutputStream(fileOut);

         int c;
         while ((c = streamIn.read()) != -1) 
         {
            streamOut.write(c);
         }

         streamIn.close();
         streamOut.close();
      }
      catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
      {
         System.err.println("FileCopy: " + e);
      } 
      catch (IOException e) 
      {
         System.err.println("FileCopy: " + e);
      }
   }
}
```

Thank you, I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest BufferedReader (for sure) and PrintWriter. PrintWriter is a richer API compared to  BufferedWriter.

Answer (score -1):

You can you `BufferedReader` and `BufferedReader` to read and write text file:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Assign4.txt"));
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter( new FileWriter("target.txt"));
    try {
        int count = 1;  
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = br.readLine();            
        while (line != null) {
            sb.append(count++);
            sb.append(line);
            sb.append("\n");
            writer.write(line);
            line = br.readLine();    
        }
    } finally {
        br.close();
        writer.close();
    }
```

Comment: Please don't do his homework for him.  The idea is to give him HINTS so that he can do it himself.

Comment: @StephenC You're right, so i just provide my suggestion, and OP should learn about `BufferedReader`, `BufferedWrite` and `StringBuilder`.